# TVM solver - Find rate if compounded quarterly

Tags: finance

I am trying to solve Question 8 using the TVM solver. The question is pretty straightforward and they ask to find the rate. I'm not sure what I did wrong, I put the following values but still not getting the right answer.
[image]

Comment: look at the dates. The last $350 is deposited Jan 1 2025, it looks like everything just sits in the bank for another year after that.

Comment: I got approx $14.37\%$. What is your attempt?